# Date representation in csv file is to be changed

Tags: spring, apache-poi, xssf, poi-hssf

When i convert xls/xlsx to csv than in that csv file date is coming as Fri Nov 11 00:00:00 IST 1988. But i need yyyy-mm-dd format. What can i do in the following code:
[code]

```
            row = (HSSFRow) rowIterator.next();

            // For each row, iterate through each columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                cell = (HSSFCell) cellIterator.next();
                    if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
                    {
                        if(HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell))
                        {

                            data.append(cell.getDateCellValue() + "|");

                        }else
                            data.append(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "|");
                    }else if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN)
                    {
                        data.append(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "|");
                    } else if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
                    {
                        data.append(cell.getStringCellValue() + "|");
                    }  
                    else if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)
                    {
                        data.append("" + "|");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        data.append(cell + ",");

                    }
            }data.append("\r\n");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For date format try this if condition on your date formatted cell.

```
if(HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell))
      {
     // data.append(cell.getDateCellValue() + "|");
      SimpleDateFormat DtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
      Date date=Test.getRow(RowNum).getCell(CellNum).getDateCellValue();
      data.append(date);
      }
```